# What's a concise way to create deep copies of a list in python?

Tags: python

s = 3*[3*[False]]

Makes a 2D, 3x3 array. But there is a problem. Deep copy doesn't fix it as the problem is with the 3*[]. Is there another way to succinctly write this command but achieve the desired behavior of a matrix of unique objects?

```
s = 3*[copy.deepcopy(3*[False])]
>>> s
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
>>> s[0][0] = True
>>>
>>> s
[[True, False, False], [True, False, False], [True, False, False]]
```

This is the best I can come up with. Are there any other ways to do it, apart from using a multi line loop?

`s = [3*[False] for i in range(3)]`

Comment: Why are you deep copying on the *inside*?

Comment: If you have NumPy you could use `np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=bool).tolist()`. But in general just use the comprehensions to create such lists, the `[3*[False] for i in range(3)]` should be fine but in case you consider using a mutable type as value, you need to use the full `[[whatever for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]`. Instead of trying to find a "short and concise way" it's often better to avoid "pitfalls by being explicit".